# What is the difference between $Q_a(x)$ and $\exists x \ Q_a(x)$

Tags: first-order-logic

When it comes to first order logic over words, what is the difference between $Q_a(x)$ and $\exists x  \ Q_a(x)$?
The signature is the usual one: $\tau = \{S, <, Q_a\} $. The universe is the set of positions in the word, $S$ is the successor and $<$ is the usual less-than relation.

$Q_a(x)$ is an atomic formula which is satisfied by all words having an '$a$' in any position of the word.
Similarly, $\exists x  \ Q_a(x)$ is also a formula which is satisfied by all words having an '$a$' in any position of the word. Both the formulae are satisfied by the same set of words.
The second formula with the $\exists$ adds just one information to the first one, that there should exist a position $x$ where an '$a$' is present, but with respect to satisfiability, both the formula seem equivalent to me as the first one too means that on the word the letter '$a$' is present.
Is there a word which is not accepted by $Q_a(x)$ but is accepted by $\exists x  \ Q_a(x)$ (or the reverse)?

Comment: I suspect you've misunderstood what $Q_a(x)$ is intended to mean. It should be satisfied by a word $W$ and an assignment $v$ if $W$ has an $a$ in the position assigned by $v$ to the variable $x$ ---  not if it has an $a$ in any old position.

Comment: So for such a word $W$, a satisfying assignment can be found iff the word $W$ contains an '$a$' and then this word will satisfy $\exists x \ Q_{a}(x)$ also, with $x$ assigned the position at which '$a$' is present.

Comment: Right. $\exists x\,Q_a(x)$ is satisfied by $v$ (in a given word) iff *some* position has $a$ and therefore *some* assignment (possibly different at $x$ from $v$) assigns to $x$ a position where the word has $a$.  In contrast, $Q_a(x)$ is satisfied by $v$ (in a given word) iff the position that $v$ assigns to $x$ (not just some other position) has $a$.

Comment: So is it right to say that the two formulae are equivalent with respect to satisfiability?

Comment: Yes; if either one is satisfiable then so is the other.